# Google Maps API, get boundary of search results

Tags: google-maps

How cloud I export coords of red polygon (e.g. boundaries of small administrative areas) from Google Maps API (JavaScript)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this manually. This [link](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org) returns a detail of a city. Like, if you search 'New York' the boundary of New York will be shown, like this:

[image]

Now if you click the detail button, you will get an OSM id which is '175905' for New York.

Now you have to go to [this link](http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py) and paste this OSM in the `Id of relation` text box and submit. You will get polyline informations in many formats.